# Problema al utilizar append() para añadir una lista dentro de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
x = int(input("Number of lists: "))
y = int(input("Amout of numbers in each list: "))

numbers = []
lists = []

for h in range(0,y):
 lists.append(0)
for k in range(0,x):
 numbers.append(lists)

for i in range(0,x):
    for j in range(0,y):
     numbers[i][j]= i*j
print(numbers)
```

En teoría, el output debería ser :

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

ya que `numbers` es igual a:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,0]]
```

pero el output que me imprime el programa es

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

He intentado correr el programa definiendo `numbers` desde un principio como :

```
[[0,0,0,0,0][[0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,0]]
```

y esa vez el output era el indicado, por lo que desconozco el problema.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. En la pregunta enlazada como duplicado tienes la explicación de lo que te pasa. Cuando haces `numbers.append(lists)` estás agregando referencias **al mismo objeto repetidamente a la lista `numbers`**. `numbers` termina con tres elementos que en realidad todos hacen referencia el mismo objeto `lists`, por lo que modificar un item es modificarlos todos (todos hacen referencia a la misma lista). Cuando inicializas `numbers` como comentas, cada sublista es un objeto distinto en cambio.